# Viewing chromium browser history by time

Tags: date, time, chromium

Chromium history allow us to browse our history by a specific word, like if I wanted to know what wikipedia pages I was browsing last week I could search by "wikipedia" then browse to last week, but is it possible to search by time, I would enter a specific date and it will bring me to what pages I was browsing around this time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The History file is a sqlite database so you can use sql to extract what you want. Create a file of sql commands called (for eg) "show.sql" with the following contents:

```
.mode line
SELECT
    DATETIME((last_visit_time/1000000)-11644473600, 'UNIXEPOCH', 'LOCALTIME') AS date,
    title,
    url
FROM
    urls
WHERE
    date < "2019-09-28 02:46:36"
    AND
    date > "2019-09-28 02:15:56"
ORDER BY
    last_visit_time;
```

and use a command like this

```
sqlite3 History < show.sql > out.txt
```

which will put the data for the date range you choose into the text file out.txt so you can browse it with an editor.

the line ".mode line" is sqlite specific and chooses the format for the output putting each field on a separate line.